# Неверные данные на выходе при запросе select(exists....)

Tags: java, mysql

1. Для работы с бд использую jdbc
2. Создаю переменную запроса: String select = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM пользователи WHERE Логин="" + login + "")";
   где login- переменная, заполняемая пользователем
3. На любое значение login команда statement.execute(select) всегда выдаёт true, хотя моя бд девственно чистая.

Что мешает грамотному чтению данных?

Comment: *На любое значение login команда statement.executeQuery(select) всегда выдаёт true* `executeQuery` всегда возвращает ResultSet. Никакого true метод не может вернуть даже теоретически.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, уже засиделся с кодом. На самом деле, изначально я пытался использовать statement.execute(select) и напрямую вывести результат. Он-то и показывает true, всегда

Comment: `execute` точно так же не может возвращать true. Он возвращает набор резальтсетов (уж не знаю, что это с самого верху - коллекция, массив или ещё какая хрень), в отличие от `executeQuery`, всегда возвращающего один резальтсет. Так что Вы за true принимаете нечто со свойством "оно не пустое".

Comment: Принял к сведению. Что тогда лучше всего применимо для получения результата запроса select exists?

Answer (score 0):

statement.execute() применимо к **update,  insert, delete** и в некоторых языках могут возвращать значения о количестве обновленных строк, новый id записи, или успехе операции удаления.

Запрос **select** возвращает набор записей (query) в формате курсор(Cursor).

Для проверки есть ли записи используется методы для определения количества записей moveToFirst, getCount.
В каждом языке они могут отличаться и выглядят примерно так

```
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from objects where x=" + x, null);
        //есть ли записи
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            objCount = c.getCount();//количество записей           
        }
        c.close();
```

Comment: Ещё погуглил и пока остановился на таком: 
boolean doesExist = statement.executeQuery(select).next();
if (doesExist)....


Всем спасибо за помощь